# Sample app for MEF for Windows App?

Tags: mef

I am new to MEF, currently I looking for sample for below

I am using a .NET 4.0 Framework base.
My requirement, I need to import WinForm in project using MEF.

Can someone please guide me or provide me sample project for the same?

Answer (score 0):

There aren't a lot of tutorials or training out there using WinForms.  However, in my research on MEF, I did come across this CodeProject article that looks like it is what you are looking for:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/WinFormsModularMefApp.aspx

I looked over the article to be sure it matched what you said you are looking for but I personally didn't follow the directions to be sure it is of good quality.  However, it does look like the article is highly-rated.